# Eclipse SVN Checkout Error E175002

Tags: eclipse, svn, github

I am receiving the following error in Eclipse Neon when attempting to do a SVN checkout from Github. I have searched google and stack overflow for similar issues and answers from previous posts are not fixing the issue.

**svn: E175002: Processing REPORT request response failed: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity**

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to identify what attempts did not work for you to suggest something.
Can you let me know if you are using SVNKit for the checkouts.
Most issues are root to either SVNKIt compatibility or JDK issues like spooling etc.,